# Using gmapping without ROS?

Tags: localization, slam, ros, mapping

Is gmapping on OpenSLAM.org still maintained? Or is the maintenance entirely over in ROS ( https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/tree/hydro-devel/gmapping ). When trying to compile gmapping without ROS I noticed that it still has Qt3 as a dependency which made me think no one uses or maintains OpenSLAM's gmapping anymore. Is this accurate? How does OpenSLAM's gmapping vs ROS's gmapping compare in terms of performance and accuracy?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this is not really related to the question but I just found Google's Cartographer. It looks pretty easy to integrate into other robotics frameworks. Has anyone played with it? What are your thoughts on it?

Answer (score 1):

Gmapping at openslam is not maintained by anyone now. You can use ros gmapping. Its accuracy will depend on your sensor but it will work pretty good if numbers of points are sufficient for scan match e.g. indoor conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Open slam is completely out of updating better you can go with the ROS stack for perception thereby you can work on your stuffs to run the codes

Answer (score 0):

OpenSLAM is completely out of box it stops updating its algorithm development better you can look at the tutorials of constructsim http://www.theconstructsim.com/ros-qa-navigate-avoiding-obstacles/
this would help you and for your second question i prefer ROS mapping than open SLAM the reason is because of its updation and visualization features!!!